# Error while referencing cell - Constant Expression Required

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

**What do I want to do?**

Line 3 of code has a time value (30 seconds) for repeating the macro after a certain time, but I'm looking anyway to, instead of writing 30 seconds in code, I want to write 30 or whatever in the `F2` cell of sheet `Record` and change time value from there every time I want.

**Solutions I have tried**

I replaced 3rd code line with below

```
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds =ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Record").Range("F2").Value

' run my code every 30 seconds or whenever I want from the F2 cell
```

Then also I got an error, so I tried to use `("$F$2")` instead of `("F2")`, but still not resolved. I'm new to VBA, but believe that some simple thing is behind it that I missing.

**The problem which is coming!**

Line no. 3 is giving me an error and `.Value` is highlighted by saying

> Compile Error: Constant Expression Required

**Below is the code**

```
Option Explicit
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Record").Range("F2").Value    ' time value in Seconds to run a macro from F2 cell

' When I use the below code in the place of 3rd line, it works fine but I need to control it from F2 cell
' Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 30

Public Const cRunWhat = "The_master" ' the name of the procedure to run
Dim FirstTime As Boolean


Sub StartTimer()

Set cRunIntervalSeconds = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Record").Range("F2").Value
If FirstTime Then
'change for today + 9:00 AM
RunWhen = Date + TimeSerial(8, 55, 0)
Else
RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
End If
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, _
Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub The_master()
Call Macro2
' Call StartTimer to run macro again
If Time > TimeSerial(12, 0, 0) Then
'do nothing
Else
StartTimer
End If
End Sub



Sub StopTimer()
'useful for testing to stop any scheduled macro
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, _
Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=False
End Sub



Sub Auto_Open()
FirstTime = True
'Change for 9:00 AM
If Time > TimeSerial(8, 55, 0) Then
FirstTime = False
End If
Call StartTimer
FirstTime = False
End Sub
```

My full code is a bit complex, it starts one macro at 9 am and then repeats it every 30 seconds till 2 pm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [Const statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/const-statement) you declare a constant.

> Declares constants for use in place of literal values.

If you want this to be variable (eg. a variable cell value, then you need to declare a variable instead of a constant!

So declare a variable

```
Public RunIntervalSeconds As Long
```

And initialize it eg on `Workbook_Open` or in the `Worksheet_Change` event of the `Record` worksheet:

```
RunIntervalSeconds = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Record").Range("F2").Value
```

After you set/initialized a value to the variabel you can use it in any module.

---

Alternatively you can use a `function` to return the value of the cell F2. If you want to avoid repeating to read the value from the cell everytime you use the function, you can use a `Static` variable so it reads it only on the first use:

```
Public Function RunIntervalSeconds(Optional ByVal ForceRefresh As Boolean = False) As Long
    Static CellValue As Long  ' this variable will keep the value because it is static
    If CellValue = 0 Or ForceRefresh Then  ' if the variable was not initialized yet read 
        ' read the value from the cell
        CellValue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Record").Range("F2").Value
    End If
    ' and return it from the function
    RunIntervalSeconds = CellValue 
End Function
```

This function can be used instead of a public variable then.

You can use it like `RunIntervalSeconds` and it will use the value that was read from the cell at it's first call or you can use `RunIntervalSeconds(ForceRefresh:=True)` to make it refresh the value from the cell.

Comment: **I still got error (Compile error: Object Requied) or something wrong I'm doing, pls have a look what is the issue** My full code https://docs.google.com/document/d/15yZCKTo0t5NDT2X3TxNBvd4cpjZtXniaz2qE_nSuSBw/edit?usp=sharing . I replaced 3rd code line with `Public RunIntervalSeconds As Long` and made 2nd code line `Set` in macro but got error. (check Bold codes)

Comment: @Gmaster Please edit your original quesiton to include the code. • Note that `Set` can only be used for objects and a `.Value` is not an object but just a value so you cannot use `Set` here. You need to do it exactly as described in my answer. Also the value of the variable needs to be written in a sub or function. You cannot do it outside the scope of a sub/function.

Comment: @Gmaster I've added an alternative

Comment: I have written all here with the changes you suggested: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YpJJww5njWwX5wS9LuWryEBqaCIGt5Qs7S-F6ZXC_lk/edit?usp=drivesdk            *CODE RUN PERFECTLY* but sometimes when I change the value 30 seconds in F2 cell to 60 seconds, it simply won't recognise it and keep running at 30 seconds and then I have to open excel file again. Also, sometimes it runs my code every 10 seconds when I write 15 in the F2 cell. Why is it happening, Is anything wrong with my code (pls check or suggest edits) or there is some other problem.

Comment: @Gmaster The value will only take the changed value from the cell if you run `RunIntervalSeconds` with `ForceRefresh` once after you updated the cell.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help, but I have **Bolded** all recently added codes in the below link, can you tell me anything wrong I might be doing according to the question I asked ( https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YpJJww5njWwX5wS9LuWryEBqaCIGt5Qs7S-F6ZXC_lk/edit?usp=drivesdk ) **There might be some other code over ruling there as now, when my macro runs, my macro sometimes repeats every step 2 times.** I'm not able to find what is behind this. Can you confirm that everything is okay according to you?